# IIS AppDomain unloading after deployment

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm deploying an ASP.NET application (just a simple Http Handler) to IIS (7.5) and I'm seeing the AppDomain unload after the first request following the deployment.

I'm just doing a simple file system deployment (copying the new files (web.config, bin folder, etc.) to the application location (C:\inetpub\wwwroot.....)) and based on messages being logged from the Application_Start and Application_End event handlers in Global asax, this is what I'm seeing:

1. The initial file copies cause the AppDomain to unload and I get a message logged via Application_End: the shutdown reason is generally 'ConfigurationChange'.
2. A request to the application causes the AppDomain to be re-loaded, so I get a message logged via Application_Start.
3. Once this request has been serviced the AppDomain is unloaded again, this time with the reason 'BuildManagerChange'.

I've tried stopping the application pool before step 1 and starting it again before step 2, but with the same result.

Searching around the web, the usual reason for a 'BuildManagerChange' shut down is that the hash.web file has changed in the Temporary ASP.NET Files folder for the app, and indeed this does seem to be what's happening in this case. As part of the application startup I'm guessing that, as part of the BuildManager initialization, it's calculating a hash of the various files in which it's interested (web.config, global.asax, etc.) and that because this is different to the value currently on file (because it's just been deployed), it's unloading the AppDomain.

So I guess my question is, why doesn't the original AppDomain unload caused by the file copying update the hash.web file? And is there any way for force this? At the moment all of the evidence suggests that it will always go through a shutdown-startup-shutdown cycle before it gets going, but I just can't believe that this is correct. Am I missing something really simple?